# how to find the most common pattern

Tags: sql

I have million records  in a MS SQL server table :

```
user1,product1,0
user1,product2,time1
user1,product3,time2
user1,product4,time3
user2,product3,0
user2,product2,time4
user3,product4,0
user3,product5,time5
```

which means user puchase product at different time.  the 3rd column is the time of purchase, when the value is 0, it means it is the first purchase of this user, assuming one use wil only purchase one item at first time.

time1, time2, time3 etc just the time difference between the first time purchase and the current purchase time.

Now I need to summarize it as:

top 10 common purchase pairs as (product , the following purchase product) and how many distinct users fit this pattern.

the result pair may look like.

```
 (product1,product2)
and (product1,product5)
and (product2,product5)
....
```

How can achieve this in SQL? Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Comment: Is this a homework? If yes, please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: Are the records in a single string with commas separating the components, or are they in three separate columns of the table?  The first is hard to deal with (please go fix the schema); the second is non-trivial, but at least you don't have to get confused sorting the data into a relational format.

Comment: Also, what is your expected output for the sample data.  (Answer both my question/comments by editing your question - not by adding comments, please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @temp table (product1 varchar, product2 varchar, user_count int)

insert into @temp (product1, product2, user_count
select pr1.product, pr2.product, count(distinct userid)
from
purchases pr1
inner join purchases pr2 on pr1.UserId = pr2.UserId and pr1.Time < pr2.Time
group by
pr1.product,
pr2.product


select top 10 * from @temp order by user_count desc
```

Comment: You need to compare on time, not just on product.  Per the OP sequence matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is better than my version, this can actually get all the pairs. I will change it as left join and add time=0, as I orignially want to get the purchase at first time and the following purchase, Thanks for your help!!